# Serializing an entity's field using Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, serialization

I've recently been working on a portal using MVC2 and I'm trying to use EF4 as the DAL.

I have an entity called WidgetInstance which serializes it's state into json. EF4 correctly identifies this as a string field but I need this to deserialize to a `List<WidgetState>` when it's loaded and serialize back to a string when saving/updating.

I've googled and SO'd for an hour or so now without much success. I don't really want to create a new DB table for the widget states.

Has anyone attempted to do this before or have any pointers where I can get started with this?

Thanks

Comment: What is the underlying database type?  Is it string (in the DB) that you split up or something?

Comment: What's the relation with ASP.NET MVC here?

Comment: yup, it's just a string. It is currently Deserialized through the JavaScriptSerializer into a List<WidgetState> and when saved it is Serialized using the same. Very easy to do with SP's in traditional ADO DAL.

Comment: It's an MVC2 app Darin, but that might be irrelevant :)

Comment: Yes, I see it's irrelevant, removing the `asp.net-mvc` tag.